# Where am I going wrong with the derivative with respect to x in this case?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need to take the partial derivatives of $f (x,y)=(x-y)^2 $ so I started with respect to x.

I tried two different approaches: one would be using the chain rule and getting $2 (x-y) *1 $ which in the end leaves me with $2x-2y $.

However, since $f(x,y)$ can also be written as $(x+y)*(x-y)$, I took the derivative of this considering the derivative of a multiplication, as $1*(x-y)+(x+y)*1 $ but this leaves me with $x-y+x+y $ which ends up being $2x$. So what am I doing wrong here for two equivalent expressions to result in different derivatives?

Comment: $(x-y)^2\neq x^2-y^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x-y)^2=x^2-2xy+y^2\neq x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$

Answer (score 0):

In your second method, the second $x+y$ should be $x-y$.

Answer (score 0):

f(x,y) **cannot be written** (x- y)(x+ y)! It is (x- y)(x- y) and using the product rule we get 1(x- y)+ (x- y)1= 2(x- y)= 2x- 2y just as you got using the chain rule